# How to redirect and allow a certain page according to the user's UID using firebase and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have a Login page and I am using `react` and `firebase`.

I am able to auth a user through email and password.

I know that I can store the user's UID somewhere in my `state` management in order to authorize him to get access to pages, etc.

The thing is that I have 3 kinds of users that I want to authenticate:

- Vendors
- Admin
- Guest

Upon authentication I wanna use `React's` `routing` to redirect the user to a different `path` according to the type of user, using `<Redirect to="path"/>`, for example:

If the logged user is a vendor => `<Redirect to="vendor"/>`

If the logged user is a guest => `<Redirect to="guest"/>`

If the logged user is a admin => `<Redirect to="admin"/>`

On Firebase I have just the authenticated users list in the users page of my project, with their password, email and `UID`. I did not figure how could I have another kind of information there where I could differentiate a type of user, not to define what `nodes` of the `DB` he hill access, but to which page, which type of `profile` he will have.

This is too abstract to share any code snippet, as I have no code bad-functioning. In this case I really do not know what to do.

The only thing that I could think of was determine on the login page what kind of user is logging in: vendor, admin, guest, store this state and redirect to a page according to the type of user, but this is really far from safe, as any registered user could end up being redirected to unauthorized pages.

Another thing that I thought of was to create a `node` in my `DB` holding an `object` with each `UID` and it's profile type, and upon auth, retrieve with the `UID` of the authenticated user, to retrieve the type of user upon an `http` request, but I am not sure if this is safe, or correct, e.g:

```
users: {
   "someUID": "vendor",
   "someOtherUID": "guest",
   "someOoootherUID": "admin"
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

In case more info is requested I will edit this post.

Comment: Yes, you need to store the users' roles in the database, but not with that structure, you can check Robin's tutorials about this: https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial

Comment: I updated his tutorial to use functional components instead of class components you can check it out here but I'm still needing to finish the authorization based on the roles: https://github.com/abdelp/react-firebase-authentication

Comment: It is better if the nodes in your db are only containing one specific user information each

Comment: This node called "users" would just check by the UID what kind of user is login in. I would then get the ```role``` back, redirect to the proper page, protect other pages and store his UID in ```redux```. Then to retrieve data, I would name the node of data with the users data in a path using the ```role``` and the ```UID``` stored. Like, for exemple, make an ```http``` request to the ```DB``` to a path ```firebase/blabla/role/UID```